# Community Promotion Ads - 2014

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's the time of the year again, namely it is December 2013, and so we shall now refresh our Community Promotion Ads for the new year.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for Jewish life and learning
- interesting in-site activities and events
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1858).

Comment: Last year [this ad](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1416), which uses the auto-updated flair for an A51 proposal as its image, worked. Now, I tried to repost it, but failed, because it's not at stack.imgur. Would it be possible to whitelist SE-network flair for this?

Comment: @IsaacMoses, unless you got an answer somehow that I don't see, you may wish to ask that question here on Meta (or on MSO if it hasn't been asked there (I haven't checked)).

Comment: @msh210, OK, done. Thanks. http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1864/please-whitelist-se-network-flair-for-use-in-community-promotion-ads

Answer (score 11):

[image: Magically convert a citation into a link on Mi Yodeya.]

Comment: Many thanks to [various community members](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9434) for providing helpful input into the design of this advertisement.

Comment: are you sure this is ok to do? I thought magic was forbidden

Comment: @pleaseremovemyaccount heh, I think it's okay. CYLOR.

Comment: @pleaseremovemyaccount Having been involved in the development, I can assure you there is no magic involved; instead, we used [practical kabbalah](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14383/883).

Answer (score 10):

[image: HebrewBooks.org]

Comment: This image was created by the fine folks at HebrewBooks, not me.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Hebrew Language]

Comment: There is a new proposal at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75348/hebrew-language because the old one got stagnant.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Sefaria: A Living library of Jewish texts]

Comment: Bachrach -- note that community ads are renewed every year, so be sure to check back here sometime in December for the 2015 ads. +1

Comment: @Shokhet Thanks for the heads up. I somehow misread the title and thought this was for next year.

Comment: No problem. This answer was worth it anyway, though, because it'll show through the end of the year -- we still have a while to go ;-)

Comment: Piece of advice -- you might want to hover your mouse over the "community ads" tag under this question, and click "subscribe," so that all new questions with this tag (meaning, the one a year) will be sent to your email, so that you'll get an automatic reminder when these questions are asked every year. ( *You could also follow the RSS feed, but that's a little more complicated* )

Answer (score 6):

[image: @mi_yodeya]

Comment: Note that **the Twitter feed linked to here is the one curated by Mi Yodeya users**. (The Twitter feed linked to from [the other ad](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1859), from which I stole this image, is the one generated automatically by a Stack Exchange corporate script.)

Answer (score -1):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Comment: I wonder if we want an ad for the standard Twitter feed (this one), the curated Mi Yodeya twitter feed, or both -- and if both, how they should be visually distinguished in the ads.  (Don't look at me for implementation; my computer-art skills are at the "I can draw freehand circles on screen shots" level. :-) )

Comment: @MonicaCellio This one has +0/−1 votes at the moment. So I guess the answer to your first question is "the curated Mi Yodeya twitter feed" (or "neither"). I don't see the problem, then, with 'stealing' this image to use for the other link (and posting a new answer here with it).

Comment: @MonicaCellio http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2015