# Please whitelist SE network flair for use in Community Promotion Ads

Tags: feature-request, advertising, area51

For 2013, [this community ad](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1416), which uses the auto-updated flair for an Area51 proposal as its image, was posted and served well as an ad. Now, I tried to repost it, but failed, because it's not at stack.imgur, which the SE engine now automatically requires for community ad posts

Would it be possible to whitelist SE-network flair for this? The flair is of the exact right format to fit these ads, and its auto-update feature makes the ad remain relevant over time. Promotion of other endeavors within the SE network seems like a type of community promotion that SE ought to support, as it benefits everyone involved.

---

For what it's worth, I've now gotten past the answer-filtering engine by posting [an answer](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1858/community-promotion-ads-2014/1865#1865) containing an imgur image and then editing it to replace the imgur image with the Area51 flair. I don't yet know whether the actual ad-generation engine will continue to let this slide. In any case, my request for actual whitelisting stands on the merits listed above, so that people can post an ad like this without rigmarole.

Comment: Pretty sure I've seen this discussed on MSO

Comment: @DoubleAA [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177445/show-area51-ads-in-the-sidebar) is the closest I've found, so far.

Comment: I'm looking into this. It came up before and I can't now, for the life of me, remember why we don't just allow 'anywhere on the network or SE imgur account'.

Comment: @TimPost, thanks for the update.